# RDP to a machine tethered by phone in NAT

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, remote-desktop, android

I need help with the following problem: I have different PCs connected to my WiFi router at home via cable, as none of them has WiFi module built-in. However, I've got another one machine, but currently I'm out of any internet cables, thus the only solution here was to connect my old phone to that PC, and tether a network via USB (while the phone is connected to WiFi). So, currently I'm able to connect to my PC via TeamViewer, but I could not connect to it through RDP. Also, all my machines have 192.168.0.*** addresses, while that connected via phone, has 172.18.***.* addresses. If there are any solutions, to connect to it throuh RDP, without going "outside" of my NAT?

Comment: It's impossible to connect a device that has an IP address in the 172.18 .x.x subnet to addresses that only exist within your own intranet assigned to the 192.168.0 subnet.  The only way you can do what you want is connect to your public IP address, provided you are NOT behind a CGNAT, by forwarding the port to your device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your phone is acting as a NAT router. Normally, you’d set up port forwarding on a NAT router to be able to connect from the outside. This is however in general not possible on phones. Only with a rooted Android would this be possible.

No, there is no easy solution. You could use an *outgoing* SSH connection (or anything that tunnels, really) from your tethered PC to another PC on the real network and set up a SSH remote port forwarding or the like.

Of course all this hinges on one critical fact: That your phone is actually using the Wi-Fi connection for the tethered PC.